# R plotly - how to update colour in a bubble chart without redrawing the plot in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, bubble-chart

I would like to update particular bubbles in a plotly bubble chart with a different colour, based on user selection in a shiny app. I do not want to completely the redraw the plot. I attempted to do this by adding a different coloured trace using plotlyProxyInvoke, but I can't work out how to specify the size of the bubble. It seems to just ignore whatever size info I give it.

[How it looks:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3Syv.jpg)

[How it is meant to look:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAQA7.jpg)

Is there a correct way to specify size for bubble charts in plotlyProxyInvoke? Or is there some other way to update the colour in the plot without redrawing it?

Below is a minimal example of what I tried.

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

d <- mtcars

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(column(12, numericInput("rownum", label = "RowID to change bubble colour", value = NULL, min = 1, max = 32))),
  fluidRow(column(12, plotlyOutput("plot")))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(d, x = ~wt, y = ~mpg, size = ~disp, type = "scatter", mode = "markers",  fill = ~'',  
            marker = list(sizemode = "diameter", line = list(width = 2, color = "white")))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$rownum, {
    
    plot_d <- d[input$rownum, ]
    plotlyProxy("plot", session) %>%
      plotlyProxyInvoke("addTraces", list(x = c(plot_d$wt, plot_d$wt),
                                          y = c(plot_d$mpg, plot_d$mpg),
                                          size = c(plot_d$disp, plot_d$disp),
                                          type = "scatter", mode = "markers",  fill = ~'', 
                                          marker = list(sizemode = "diameter", color = "black",
                                                        line = list(width = 2, color = "white"))))
    
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to invoke the `restyle` method:

```r
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

d <- mtcars

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(column(12, actionButton("btn", "Change color"))),
  fluidRow(column(12, plotlyOutput("plot")))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(d, x = ~wt, y = ~mpg, size = ~disp, type = "scatter", 
            mode = "markers",  fill = ~'', 
            marker = list(
              sizemode = "diameter", 
              line = list(width = 2, color = "white"))
            )
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$btn, {
    plotlyProxy("plot", session) %>%
      plotlyProxyInvoke(
        "restyle", 
        list(marker = list(color = "red", size = mtcars$disp/2))
      )
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

That works for the color. However I don't understand what happens for the size. If I put `list(marker = list(color = "red", size = mtcars$disp))` then the circles are very bigger than the original ones.

---

## Edit

This is consistent if you set the size in the `marker` list:

```r
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(d, x = ~wt, y = ~mpg, type = "scatter", 
            mode = "markers",  fill = ~'', 
            marker = list(
              size = d$disp,
              sizemode = "diameter", 
              line = list(width = 2, color = "white"))
            )
  })
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Stéphane, it's interesting that it doesn't seem possible to specify the size attribute outside of the marker list and also get the plot to update without redrawing. This was very helpful though, I will have a play around with your suggestions.